# How to select a form with xpath in Mechanize/Python?

Tags: python, xpath, screen-scraping, mechanize

I am visiting a stateful web service with mechanize/Python. It confirm the referrer of a request and my browser's cookie.
Since most forms of the site don't have name attribute, I'm tired to select forms.

I would like to use xpath like `//*[@id="top"]/div[3]/form/input[@type="submit"]` and submit it.
Do you have any ideas to select forms with xpath?

Comment: The xpath expression seems ok.

Comment: I don't think python mechanize has xpath support. You should probably look into lxml's `xpath` and `submit_form`. Or try to use mechanize and lxml somehow together.

Comment: Thanks for giving me the idea! I may be able to get the position of a target form in a page by lxml. So I try to use lxml and mechanize.Browser.select_form(nr=).